# jquery validation with chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I created a select element, set to allow multiple selection and integrated chosen plugin with optgroups like below:

```
<select id="attributes" name="data[attributes]" multiple>
 <optgroup label="Color" class="max_one">
   <option value="Black">Black</option>
   <option value="Yellow">Yellow<option>
   <option value="Red">Red</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Year">
   <option value="2006">2006</option>
   <option value="2007">2007</option>
   <option value="2008">2008</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Top Speed" class="max_one">
   <option value="120">120m/h</option>
   <option value="140">140m/h</option>
   <option value="160">160m/h</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

The user can select multiple values from each optgroup obviously.

I want to add a method to jquery validation and make sure, that **at least and only 1** option is selected from each optgroup with class **.max_one**, using jquery validation.

I have tried the **require_from_group: [1, ".max_one"]** function but it only works with plain checkboxes.

Comment: From a GUI perspective, IMO, this is a really bad design.  It seems cumbersome as the potential exists where, if invalid, the user will have to start over from scratch multiple times.

Comment: It depends, its a really large form and I am trying to avoid splitting each group to a single select dropdown. Combined with chosen plugin (autocomplete search), it is a fair solution.

Comment: If you come up with a good solution, it's safe to say it will be unique among the thousands of SO questions tagged with jQuery Validate.

Answer (score 1):

@Sparky said it was out of the capabilities of jquery-validate, but maybe something like this will help you.

```
$('#attributes').on('change', function () {
    $('.max_one').each(function () {
        $('option').each(function () {
            if ($('option:selected').length == 1) {
                // Valid
            } else {
                // Invalid  
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of that kind of solution. There must be a way to put that in a custom method in jquery validation.

Answer (score 0):

`require_from_group` has nothing specific to do with checkbox elements.  It works on a "group" of input elements.  `input`, `select` or `textarea` are the only valid elements.

However, in your case, there is only ONE input element... a single `select`.  And since `option` elements are children of a `select` element, they are not validated on their own.

In other words, the `require_from_group` method is not going to recognize `option` or `optgroup` elements as input elements; only the parent `select` as a single input.

Comment: Correct about the input element @Sparky. But there's no way to count selected options for each optgroup with class .max_one? Using addMethod() ?

Comment: @mallix, sure, count them, but then you're doing validation outside of the scope of the plugin.  If you're looking for a jQuery Validate solution, I don't believe it's possible.